# Count the maximum consecutive times a string appears in a column in excel

Tags: excel

I have a column of data and I want to find the maximum number of times a string appears consecutively in it.
For example:

```
Adam
Adam
Adam
John
Alice
Alice
```

The output should be 3 here.

Comment: And if there is another Adam at the end it's still 3? Excel only or VBA also?

Comment: Yep, will still be three.
VBA is okay too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper column and then resume data with Pivot Tables or formulas:

[image]

Sorting for this solution is critical or it won't work!

Formula in column B is:

```
=IF(A2=A1;B1+1;1)
```

This will output increasing count if name is the same. If not, it will restart count to 1.

Then you can use this with Pivot Tables or formulas to get max count for each name.

With Pivot Tables is easier, just drag field `Name` into rows section and `Count` into values section, but **make sure** you set it up to max instead of summing up.

Another option would be formula. You can use MAXIFS to get max count for each name. In case you don't have MAXIFS available because your Excel is old like mine, you can use the formula I've used in cell `G17`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($A$2:$A$14=F17)*$B$2:$B$14))
```